# Can we be assume that the RecyclerView.ViewHolder always contains the same items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Supposing that we have a RecyclerView (simulating a ListView):

[image]

1. Can assume that the RecyclerView.ViewHolder always contains the same items (an item is a single item in the adapter)?
2. Thus, if the RecyclerView.ViewHolder doesn't contains the item, Can assume that this element is not displayed ?

Comment: What does "item" mean in your question? Using your screenshot, is an "item" a country? Is an "item" a widget in one of the rows? Is an "item" something else?

Comment: Item means a single item on the adapter, in the image, means a single row of the adapter (Country flag, country name , country description, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

> Can assume that the RecyclerView.ViewHolder always contains the same items?

**No**

The idea for `RecyclerView` is to reuse the same `ViewHolder` objects to display different stuff.

> Thus, if the RecyclerView.ViewHolder doesn't contains the item, Can assume that this element is not displayed ?

**No**

That's because this item could have been displayed by some `ViewHolder` instance, and then passed to another `ViewHolder` instance.

PS. I'm assuming that by "item" you mean a single element from the adapter.